# change column type based on condition of variables

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tibble

I have data, of which this is a small sample:

```
df <- structure(list(`d955` = c("1", "4", NA, NA), 
                `65c2` = c("6a08", NA, "6a08", "6a09")), 
                 class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
                 row.names = c(NA, -4L), .Names = c("d955", "65c2"))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#    d955 `65c2`
#   <chr>  <chr>
# 1     1   6a08
# 2     4   <NA>
# 3  <NA>   6a08
# 4  <NA>   6a09
```

Both columns are character types. I want to change the columntype of all columns that contain just numbers from 1 to 5 to integer. I know I could handpick the columns to do this, but because the columns will continuously change this is not a satisfiable option.

So how to do this automatically? I have been looking into `mutate_if` from the `dplyr` package, but I don't know how to select the right column to begin with.

I have been looking into `str_detect`, which might work, but something like `str_detect(df, "[1234]")` will also match strings in the `65c2` row with a number between 1-4. I have been looking at solutions with `str_count`, because the integers will always have count of 1, but I don't find a good solution to select columns based on a stringcount condition...

Desired automated result:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#    d955 `65c2`
#   <int>  <chr>
# 1     1   6a08
# 2     4   <NA>
# 3  <NA>   6a08
# 4  <NA>   6a09
```

Comment: Have been trying tidyverse approaches like `charcount <- function(x) (str_count(x) == 1)` in combination with `users.matrix %>% mutate_if(charcount, as.integer)`. That doesn't work, but i guess it would be a possible route aswell...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An idea via base R,

```
i1 <- colSums(sapply(df, function(i) i %in% c(NA, 1:5))) == nrow(df)
df[i1] <- lapply(df[i1], as.integer)
```

which gives,

> ```
> str(df)
> Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
>  $ d955: int  1 4 NA NA
>  $ 65c2: chr  "6a08" NA "6a08" "6a09"
> ```

You can also make it a function,

```
my_conversion <- function(df){
  i1 <- colSums(sapply(df, function(i) i %in% c(NA, 1:5))) == nrow(df)
  df[i1] <- lapply(df[i1], as.integer)
  return(df)
}
```

Comment: ah, great! This works. Will accept your answer after stack lets me do so :)

Answer (score 3):

A solution using the `mutate_if` from the `dplyr` package. We will need to define a predicate function (`is_one_five_only`) for this task.

```
library(dplyr)

# Design a function to determine if elements from one vector are all 1 to 5
# Notice that if the entire column is NA, it will report FALSE
is_one_five_only <- function(x){
  if (all(is.na(x))){
    return(FALSE)
  } else {
    x2 <- x[!is.na(x)]
    return(all(x2 %in% 1:5))
  }
}

# Apply is_one_five_only as the predicate function in mutate_if
df2 <- df %>% mutate_if(is_one_five_only, as.integer)
df2

# # A tibble: 4 x 2
#   d955 `65c2`
#   <int>  <chr>
# 1     1   6a08
# 2     4   <NA>
# 3    NA   6a08
# 4    NA   6a09
```

Answer (score 1):

using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

# get indices of all the character columns
# (i.e. we can skip numeric/other columns)
char_cols = sapply(df, is.character)

# := is the assignment operator in data.table --
#  since data.table is built for efficiency,
#  this differs from base R or dplyr assignment
# since assignment with := is _by reference_,
#  meaning no copies are created. there are other
#  advantages of :=, like simple assignment
#  by group -- see the intro vignettes
#.SD is a reflexive reference -- if .SDcols
#  is unspecified, it simply refers to your
#  data.table itself -- df[ , .SD] is the same as df.
#  .SDcols is used to restrict which columns are
#  included in this Subset of the Data -- here,
#  we only include character columns.
#Finally, by lapply-ing .SD, we essentially loop
#  over the specified columns to apply our
#  custom-tailored function
df[ (char_cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) {
  if (any(grepl('[^1-5]', x))) x
  else as.integer(x)
}, .SDcols = char_cols]
```

hopefully the conversion logic is clear; can elaborate as needed.

See the [Getting Started wiki](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) for a primer and a wealth of other resources for acculturating yourself to the essentials of `data.table`.

Comment: I don't completely follow what you do. Why get the char col indices? To speed things up for large matrices? And, I have never seen the use of := in R (though, I know it from Mathematica), so interesting to learn the option. What's the function of the .SD and .SDcols?

Comment: @raoul `:=` is used in the `data.table` package to create a new variable by reference or to replace/update an existing variable. See the `data.table` intro on their github page or check out other examples on SO. Also, take a look at the detailed comments added to this answer.